# Buddy system allocator in linux kernel

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

I have a doubt related to buddy system allocator in Linux kernel.

Consider this example:

[image]

Assume there is 128KB RAM on which buddy system is allocating.
If i allocate 32KB using kmalloc, my understanding is,

128KB is split into two 64KB in step 1 and the first 64KB is split into two 32KB.
Then the first 32KB is allocated to me.

Clearly 96KB of contiguous memory is still available.

Now if i allocate 90KB at this stage, what happens?
will kmalloc fail or buddy (or even slab) allocator handle this and successfully allocate requested memory?

Answer (score 4):

After first 32KB, you could not allocate anything bigger than 64KB. `kmalloc()` returns `nullptr` in such a case.

This is true for a buddy allocator. A slab allocator works differently, but this is off topic.

Comment: why isn't this a big problem in using buddy allocator? Because you'll always have enough total memory?

Comment: @aneeshjoshi could you reformulate your questions? I don't get what you are trying to ask

Comment: Sorry about that. The above limitation seems like a major problem to me. does the above scenario happen often in real systems? if yes, why would the buddy allocator still be used?

Comment: Buddy allocator works fast and it's easy to implement, that comes with a price though. One of them is mentioned above memory 'fragmentation'. Another is memory allocated with granularity of chunk size. Saying that, suppose you ask for 4 bytes of memory, if chunk size is 1KByte, you would be given a whole 1KB, next 4 bytes would take another 1KB, etc. Regarding 'real systems', they might be a different kind not only your desktop PC and behave respectively of their design. I could not talk for all of them. Linux, for all I know, does not use buddy allocator these days.